# Building a room with openGL in java

Tags: java, opengl

I am trying to build a room using openGl, and to place the camera in it, but for some reason when I try to modify glu.gluLookAt() it just changes the perspective of the viewing instead of placing the camera inside the room. Here is the code:

```
    public void display(GLAutoDrawable gLDrawable) {
    final GL2 gl = gLDrawable.getGL().getGL2();
    gl.glClear(GL2.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL2.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
    gl.glLoadIdentity();  // Reset The View
    gl.glTranslatef(0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f);

    glu.gluLookAt( 0.1,0.1,-0.1,
                     0.5, 0.5, -0.5, 
                     0, 1, 0 );



    gl.glTexParameteri ( GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL2.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, GL2.GL_REPEAT );
    gl.glTexParameteri( GL2.GL_TEXTURE_2D,GL2.GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, GL2.GL_REPEAT );

    gl.glBegin(GL2.GL_QUADS);
    // Front Face
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(2f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(2f, 1.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    // Back Face
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    // Top Face
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    // Bottom Face
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    // Right face
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    // Left Face
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, -1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 0.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, -1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glTexCoord2f(0.0f, 1.0f);
    gl.glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, -1.0f);
    gl.glEnd();
}
```

[image]

Comment: What's that `glTranslatef()` before your `gluLookAt()` for?

Comment: I saw glTranlatef() as an example for building a box, so I used it, and then added gluLookAt(). Is this why I have this problem?

Comment: I dont know the lib you are using, but if both matrices are pushed on the same matrix stack, than you may have to swap the order of your matrices. Try: `glu.gluLookAt(...);` and after this do the translation. Matrix multiplication is not commutative, so this may be the problem.